# Flash running extremely slowly

Tags: performance, flash, debugging, actionscript, actionscript-2

I work in an office where we all have the same hardware (intel core duo processors and 4GB RAM); we all have the exact same desktop PCs.

I have been building an application in flash that is running very smoothly on my machine, no visible lag. However when some of my colleagues view it on their machine it is horrendously laggy and very slow.

My code has been highly optimized, I know it is not a memory leak problem .etc especially since my computer has the same specs and runs the flash fine.

Things to note, it is written in AS2 (yes, I know it is less efficient but this is not my choice). The majority of flash player versions are 10+ (using the browser plugin) and the application is set to run at 32 FPS.

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to work out from the current description, but can your try with different players ? The release flash player in browser vs debug player in Flash IDE will give different speeds. Also I think the debug (Test Movie) swf is slightly different from the release (Publish) swf (which should be optimized a bit)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Hi George, thanks for responding. I have tested this also using my browser player which is at the same version as my colleagues (10.2) and it is running smoothly. I realise it is hard to come to a conclusion as I am unable to display the application here.

Comment: open [this page](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/08/checking-the-users-flash-player-capabilities-using-the-flashsystemcapabilities-class/) on the computer you're testing, scroll down to the embedded swf and in the list displayed check if isDebugger(DEB) is set to true - this tells you if the machine is using the debugger version of the player or not. Typically the release version is faster, but there are exceptions. Also, compile two versions of the swf: one using Test Movie and another using Publish and check if there are any differences. HTH

Answer (score 0):

@George Reith - Uncheck - Enable hardware acceleration through Settings by right clicking on swf on your colleagues machine